# How to do client exporting of ZK chart using fallbackToExportServer property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, zk

ZK charts are using Highchart inside. Highcharts uses its own server to export charts (Like PNG,PDF etc). I want to implement client side exporting and  I don't want to send my data to any external server.

I am following the below link

[Highchart API for Client side export][1]   , 
[JS fiddle example][2]

Based on the links,  I am looking for ZK Chart equivalent for 'fallbackToExportServer' property of high chart.  But not able to find the equivalent property, please let me know if you aware of it.

```
 [1]: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export
  [2]: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/offline-download-demo/
```

Comment: Which version of ZK charts do you use? From what I have found, the offline exporting is available form v3.0.0 (https://www.zkoss.org/product/zkcharts/releasenote/3.0.0).

Comment: Yes. ZK charts v3.0.0 support offline export. But am using version 1.0.1

Comment: So it looks like you need to update your version in order to make use of the offline exporting feature.

Comment: I can't update high-chart version or ZK Chart version. Is there any alternative way to do the exporting?

Comment: Can't you just use Highcharts exporting module (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview)?